# What is the proper way to create a Header with python?

Tags: ros, python, std-msgs, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I seem unable to find what the proper procedure is to fill a std_msgs/Header field in a message using python.

I have found this for C++:

```
my_message message; // using a std_msgs/Header called header
message.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
message.header.seq++;
```

This example builds its own timestamp, increases the sequence number (which was not predefined), and ignores the frame field. Is this correct, and, more importantly, what is the equivalent Python code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60209/what-is-the-proper-way-to-create-a-header-with-python?/) by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-08**:
You should not set the sequence field, it is set when you publish a message containing the Header.

**Comment by [divi](https://answers.ros.org/users/40566/divi/) on 2022-07-07**:
Hi @RafBerkvens , @jbohren , I'm facing the same problem, seq is incremented by publisher and I set
message.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
in a callback function and i don't see anything in stamp while publishing.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Necessary imports:

```
import rospy
import std_msgs.msg
```

Create the structure:

```
h = std_msgs.msg.Header()
h.stamp = rospy.Time.now() # Note you need to call rospy.init_node() before this will work
```

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 26

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-04-08**:
How does this relate to the comment @joq posted on the original question, stating that the sequence field should not be set?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-04-09**:
Updated the answer, `seq` is set for you by the publisher.